# Есть ли аналог layout_below в constraint_layout android?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

У меня есть такая разметка на основе RelativeLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    tools:context=".screens.homeScreen.PersonalPage">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/userFoto_k"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:translationZ="15dp"
        android:focusable="true" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/userData_k"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="#999A9C"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_semibold">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userName_k"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="155dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="24sp"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="8sp"
            app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userID_k"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/userName_k"
            android:layout_marginStart="155dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_semibold"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="24sp"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="8sp"
            app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />


    </RelativeLayout>


    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_1_k"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/userData_k"
        android:layout_marginTop="1.5dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userMail_k"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/view_1_k"
        android:layout_marginStart="155dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_regular"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/gray"
        app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="24sp"
        app:autoSizeMinTextSize="8sp"
        app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />


    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_2_k"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.75dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/userMail_k"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@color/test_color" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/current_pos_layout_k"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/userFoto_k"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:background="#F2F2F2"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/currentPosition_k"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_location"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_semibold"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="20sp"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="8sp"
            app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/location_k"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_location_pointer"
            android:drawablePadding="6dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_semibold"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="20sp"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="8sp"
            app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/edit_profile_k"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/current_pos_layout_k"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/main_screen_btn"
        android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_semibold"
        android:text="@string/edit_user_profile"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/main_scr_more_btn_k"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/current_pos_layout_k"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/edit_profile_k"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-75dp"
        android:background="@drawable/main_scr_circle_btn"
        android:foreground="@drawable/ic_three_dots_more_indicator"
        android:foregroundGravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView_k"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/main_scr_more_btn_k"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

я хочу ее перевести на `constraintLayout` так как он дает намного больше возможностей (адаптивность например) по сравнению с RelativeLayout. Вот что у меня сейчас есть:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    tools:context=".screens.homeScreen.PersonalPage">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/userFoto_k"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:translationZ="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.constraint.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="right"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="userData_k,userMail_k"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="411dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/userData_k"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="#999A9C"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_semibold"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userName_k"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="155dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="24sp"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="8sp"
            app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userID_k"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/userName_k"
            android:layout_marginStart="155dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_semibold"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="24sp"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="8sp"
            app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />


    </RelativeLayout>


    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_1_k"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1.5dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/userData_k"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userMail_k"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_regular"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/gray"
        app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="24sp"
        app:autoSizeMinTextSize="8sp"
        app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"

        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/userFoto_k"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/userFoto_k"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view_1_k" />


    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_2_k"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.75dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@color/test_color"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/userMail_k"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/current_pos_layout_k"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/userFoto_k"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:background="#F2F2F2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/userFoto_k">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/currentPosition_k"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_location"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_semibold"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="20sp"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="8sp"
            app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/location_k"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_location_pointer"
            android:drawablePadding="6dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_semibold"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="20sp"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="8sp"
            app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/edit_profile_k"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/current_pos_layout_k"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/main_screen_btn"
        android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_semibold"
        android:text="@string/edit_user_profile"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/main_scr_more_btn_k"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/current_pos_layout_k" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/main_scr_more_btn_k"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/current_pos_layout_k"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"

        android:background="@drawable/main_scr_circle_btn"
        android:foreground="@drawable/ic_three_dots_more_indicator"
        android:foregroundGravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"


        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/edit_profile_k"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/current_pos_layout_k" />

    <android.support.constraint.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="main_scr_more_btn_k,edit_profile_k"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="277dp" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView_k"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"

        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/userFoto_k" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

две проблемы которые я не смог решить:

1. Список каким-то непонятным образом не хочет опускаться под кнопки и висит на весь экран, хотя в relativeLayout все решается просто тегом below.
2. Текстовое поле с id `userMail_k` не может отображаться от правого края картинки imageview а начинает отображение от левого края макета.

Я читал что можно использовать barrier для решения моих проблем, но не очень понял как именно его нужно использовать, в итоге решил спросить здесь.

Comment: Может быть, поможет этот вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42356961/how-to-position-below-the-lowest-of-two-views-in-constraintlayout, если Вы еще не читали его

Comment: @Анастасия, спасибо большое он мне частично помог, я смог разместить список под кнопками изменив высоту на 0dp, но теперь список не может быть проскроллен на всю длину :(

Comment: вообще ConstraintLayout не предполагает вложенности других контейнеров, если не получается сверстать одноуровневую верстку, лучше не использовать ConstraintLayout вовсе, потому что преимущества его не используются, а сам он "тяжелее" прочих.

Comment: @pavlofff, тогда получается лучше использовать первый вариант и все? тогда в чем прелесть constraint_layout?

Comment: ну, задумывался он именно как контейнер для одноуровневой верстки, чтобы избежать вложенности контейнеров. сейчас это уже некий "монстр", который включает в себя все более менее известные способы верстки и связей и даже анимации (через MotionLayout, который является его наследником). Вообще неплохо бы приложить скрин, как должно выглядеть, по первой разметке детали не понятны, но я там не вижу ничего, что требовало бы вложенности для ConstraintLayout